# 日本語に違和感: 「質問する」のタイトルの初期テキスト

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

「プログラミングに関しての質問は何ですか？具体的に説明してください。」

↓以下の方が自然だと思います

「プログラミングに関しての質問は何ですか？具体的に書いてください。」

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 直接編集できないため、少々時間がかかりますが、後日適用します。